# How can I use my blog page as the homepage but only for mobile/tablet visits?

Tags: mobile, frontpage

How can I provide my blog page as the front page for mobile visitors including any portable device such as tablets and phones?

My actual static frontpage as defined in the backend standard options should  only be displayed to notebook, desktop and wide screen devices.

Is this possible?

Comment: This doesn't fit the site format, this is a Q&A site not a discussion board, you need a specific solvable thing to ask about, something you can mark an answer as the factually correct answer for all people with this question. This looks like a subjective discussion asking for recommendations and opinions, I don't see anyway for you to declare a response as the official correct answer, or for it to stand the test of time

Comment: Thanks! I edited the questions and resubmitted it for review!

Comment: I've reopened it and made some adjustments to make it easier to read. What you want is going to need to require a redirect, and may even have associated SEO penalties. Normally you would use CSS media breakpoints to adjust how a page is styled but you've explicitly mentioned here that the content is different and it is not the same page but with different parts shown/hidden or restyled, but a completely different page. You may also find that the answer you get can't be used because of how you built that homepage, I'm assuming it's built using a pagebuilder?